# Step by step explaintions needed for integral problems

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

[first promblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXYBn.png)

First problem: I have no idea where to start with the problem, so little a direction on where to start would be very appreciated.

[second promblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h7Kf.png)

[my handwritten work for second problem (sorry it's sideways)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnBf8.jpg)

second problem: I'm stuck on the last step of verifying my identity, I honestly have no idea how to move forward so a walkthrough of the steps would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(\pi)-f(e)=21$

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, stare at the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus until you see why what you were given shows that the theorem applies. Then we have
$$
21=\int_e^\pi f'(x) \;dx = f(x)\bigg|_e^\pi = f(\pi)-f(e)=f(\pi)-13
$$
But then $f(\pi)-13=21$ so that $f(\pi)=34$.

For the second problem, 
$$
\begin{split}
2 \int_a^x f(t) \; dt = 2 \sin x -1 \\
\int_a^x f(t) \; dt = \sin x - \frac{1}{2}
\end{split}
$$ Differentiate and use the Fundamental Theoem of Calculus:
$$
\begin{split}
\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t) \; dt &= \dfrac{d}{dx} \left[\sin x - \frac{1}{2}\right] \\
f(x) &= \cos x 
\end{split}
$$
Now it is just a matter of finding the value $a$.
$$
\int_a^x f(t) \; dt = \int_a^x \cos t \; dt = \sin t \,\bigg|_a^x= \sin x - \sin a 
$$
But we need this to be $\sin x - \frac{1}{2}$. Then $\sin x - \sin a = \sin x - \frac{1}{2}$. This means $\sin a = \frac{1}{2}$. But then we need $a= \arcsin \frac{1}{2}= \frac{\pi}{6}$. In short, you had all the right ideas!

Answer (score 0):

First problem: think Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Second problem: You're almost there. Evaluate the integral: $\int_{\frac\pi6}^x \cos t dt = \sin t|_\frac\pi6^x = \sin x - \sin\frac\pi6$